# Knex.js - How to create unique index with 'where' clause?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm using Knex.js. I'd like to create a unique index for my table with WHERE clause:

```
db.schema.createTable('newTable', function(t) {
  t.increments()
  t.string('col1').defaultTo(null)
  t.string('col2').notNullable()
  t.integer('col3').notNullable()
  t.unique(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).whereNotNull('col1')
  t.unique(['col2', 'col3']).whereNull('col1')
})
```

I try to create two partial indexes for the table. However, `whereNotNull` is not chainable with `unique` function. How to create a unique index with 'where' clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial index is not yet supported. There is PR which is not ready yet though https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/pull/2401.

For now one has to use knex.schema.raw for it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
   knex.schema.raw(
      `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_partial_newTable_col1_col2_col3" ON "newTable" ("col1", "col2", "col3") WHERE "col1" IS NOT NULL`
    );

   knex.schema.raw(
      `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_partial_newTable_col2_col3" ON "newTable" ("col2", "col3") WHERE "col1" IS NULL`
    );
```

Comment: not sure why someone gave this answer a thumbs down. this should work

Answer (score 0):

one can use below syntax to create index with conditions

```
knex.table('users', function (table) 
{
    table.index(['name', 'last_name'], 'idx_name_last_name', {
      indexType: 'FULLTEXT',
      storageEngineIndexType: 'hash',
      predicate: knex.whereNotNull('email'),
    });
});
```

or

```
knex.table('users', function (table) 
{
    table.index(['name', 'last_name'], 'idx_name_last_name', {
      indexType: 'unique',
      storageEngineIndexType: 'hash',
      predicate: knex.whereRaw('email=false'),
    });
});
```

extra example

Answer (score 0):

With [this](https://github.com/knex/knex/pull/5316) merged, now in order create unique index in knex we can do

```
db.schema.createTable('newTable', function(t) {
  t.increments()
  t.string('col1').defaultTo(null)
  t.string('col2').notNullable()
  t.integer('col3').notNullable()
  t.unique(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], {
    useConstraint: false,
    predicate: knex.whereNotNull('col1')
  })
  t.unique(['col2', 'col3'], {
    useConstraint: false,
    predicate: knex.whereNull('col1')
  })
})
```