# how to perform sql actions/query for duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, knex.js

I have 2 tables:

1-`brokers`(this is a company that could have multiple broker individuals)

and

2-`brokerIndividuals` (A person/individuals table that has a foreign key of broker company it belongs to and  the individuals details)

I'm trying to create a unique index column for `brokers` table where the fields `companyName` are unique and `isDeleted` is NULL. Currently, the table is already populated so  I want to write an SQL QUERY to find duplicate rows and whenever there are rows with the same `companyName` and `isDeleted=NULL`, I would like to perform 2 actions/queries:

1-keep the first row as it is and changes other duplicates(rows following the first duplicate) rows' `isDeleted` columns value to `true`.

2- associate or change the foreign key in `brokerIndividuals` for the duplicate rows for the first row.

The verbal description of what I am trying to do is: soft delete the duplicate rows and associate their corresponding `brokerIndividuals` to the first occurrence of duplicates. Table needs to have 1 occurrence of `companyName` where `isDeleted` is `NULL`.

I am using knex.js ORM so if that help's you can also suggest a solution using knex functions but knex doesn't support partial index yet( [Knex.js - How to create unique index with 'where' clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171952/knex-js-how-to-create-unique-index-with-where-clause) ) so I have to use the raw SQL method. Plus the DB I'm using is mssql(version: 6.0.1).

Comment: This sounds like a one-time only operation - it's an easy operation in standard SQL, do you need a knex-specific solution? If not tag the specific database platform.

Comment: Hi @Stu, I don't mind a knex specific solution but I think a SQL query would be more appreciated. The database we are using is MySql.

Comment: You'll have a problem trying to create a direct `UNIQUE` constraint on a composite where one of the values can be `null`, since null = null won't violate the constraint.

Comment: The error you showed me doesn't appear to be a MySQL error.  What database (and version) are you really using?  Adjust the tags in question to match.  If the error is from your interface layer, you may have restrictions unrelated to or outside the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full test case (commented), with link to the fiddle:

[Working test case, tested with MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 8.0 and MariaDB up to 10.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=4686744aa16d64c6ae1359a72aaf126d)

Create the tables and insert initial data with duplicate `company_name` entries:

```
CREATE TABLE brokers (
     id           int  primary key auto_increment
   , company_name VARCHAR(30)
   , isDeleted    boolean default null
);

CREATE TABLE brokerIndividuals (
     id           int  primary key auto_increment
   , broker_id    int references brokers (id)
);

INSERT INTO brokers (company_name) VALUES
     ('name1')
   , ('name1')
   , ('name1')
   , ('name1')
   , ('name123')
   , ('name123')
   , ('name123')
   , ('name123')
;

INSERT INTO brokerIndividuals (broker_id) VALUES
    (2)
  , (7)
;

SELECT * FROM brokers;

+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | company_name | isDeleted |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | name1        |      null |
|  2 | name1        |      null |
|  3 | name1        |      null |
|  4 | name1        |      null |
|  5 | name123      |      null |
|  6 | name123      |      null |
|  7 | name123      |      null |
|  8 | name123      |      null |
+----+--------------+-----------+


SELECT * FROM brokerIndividuals;

+----+-----------+
| id | broker_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         2 |
|  2 |         7 |
+----+-----------+
```

Adjust brokers to determine isDeleted based on the `MIN(id)` per `company_name`:

```
UPDATE brokers
  JOIN (
         SELECT company_name, MIN(id) AS id
           FROM brokers
          GROUP BY company_name
       ) AS x
    ON x.company_name = brokers.company_name
   AND isDeleted IS NULL
   SET isDeleted = CASE WHEN (x.id <> brokers.id) THEN 1 END
;
```

The updated brokers contents:

```
SELECT * FROM brokers;

+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | company_name | isDeleted |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | name1        |      null |
|  2 | name1        |         1 |
|  3 | name1        |         1 |
|  4 | name1        |         1 |
|  5 | name123      |      null |
|  6 | name123      |         1 |
|  7 | name123      |         1 |
|  8 | name123      |         1 |
+----+--------------+-----------+
```

For `brokerIndividuals`, find / set the correct `broker_id`:

```
UPDATE brokerIndividuals
  JOIN brokers AS b1
    ON b1.id = brokerIndividuals.broker_id
  JOIN brokers AS b2
    ON b1.company_name = b2.company_name
   AND b2.isDeleted IS NULL
   SET brokerIndividuals.broker_id = b2.id
;
```

New contents:

```
SELECT * FROM brokerIndividuals;

+----+-----------+
| id | broker_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         5 |
+----+-----------+
```

Comment: running this query gives a syntax error. The error I get  is :  migration failed with error: `UPDATE OriginationAdmin.Brokers
        JOIN (
               SELECT CompanyName, MIN(Id) AS Id
                 FROM OriginationAdmin.Brokers
                GROUP BY CompanyName
             ) AS x
          ON x.CompanyName = OriginationAdmin.Brokers.CompanyName
         AND isDeleted IS NULL
         SET isDeleted = CASE WHEN (x.Id <> OriginationAdmin.Brokers.Id) THEN 1 END
       - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
RequestError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'`